# Aws4 singning: What is URI parameter mention in Task 1: Create a Canonical Request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, signing

In aws doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

Step2: The canonical URI is the URI-encoded version of the absolute path component of the URI, which is everything in the URI from the HTTP host to the question mark character ("?") that begins the query string parameters (if any).  What does it means?

Can you explain with this Example request https://customer-service.example.com/dev/customer/?name=alex&country=us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer aws4 npm package. [It is well documented in it's github's page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017884/aws4-singning-what-is-uri-parameter-mention-in-task-1-create-a-canonical-reque)

In its documentation, AWS recommends using aws-sdk since URL signing could become tedious for a very simple task (like get an s3 object) . We used aws4 because importing aws-sdk in our code brought unnecessary dependencies.

Below is an example for Listing Secrets from aws secretmanager.

In example below,

- AWS service is indicated by service: 'secretsmanager'
- action is indicated by "X-Amz-Target": "secretsmanager.ListSecrets"

You can refer to corrospoding aws service's API to modify below example for your need.

Please note below examples assumes ec2 have correct role assigned to carry out this request. That is why you will see it is using sts in below example.

If your case is different then please check [documentation](https://github.com/mhart/aws4#readme) to check how secret key is passed via aws4 api.

```
var http  = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),
    aws4  = require('aws4')

request(aws4.sign({service: 'sts', path: '/?Action=GetSessionToken&Version=2011-06-15'}))

function request(o) { https.request(o, function(res) { res.pipe(process.stdout) }).end(o.body || '') }

request(aws4.sign({
    service: 'secretsmanager',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/',
    headers: {
        "Accept-Encoding": "identity",
        "X-Amz-Target": "secretsmanager.ListSecrets",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1"
    },
    body: '{}'
  }))
```

Comment: In my case i need to create signature by also adding my own timestamp. In aws4, the limitation is each time , it return different signature even for same values. As it create signature with current date-time. that's why i am creating my own util to sign the request using aws4.

Comment: In aws4 source file, RequestSigner.prototype.getDateTime()  is checking if date(timestamp)was passed by header. Did you try passing custom timestamp in headers via X-Amz-Date. Obejct that you pass to sign method takes headers.

Comment: No i didn't have an idea about it, as its not mention in aws4 documentation. Let me try it.